How do you, or can you, create and/or "adjust" an NSLayoutAnchor property?
Say you have some large complex custom view,
lazy var pinkThing: ..
lazy var greenThing: ..

And you want to
///For upstream views to use as they wish
var pinkCenterY: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor {
    return pinkThing.centerYAnchor
}

which is fine. You could also (pointlessly)
///For programmers who prefer to type .example than .topAnchor
var example: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor {
    return topAnchor
}

Say you want to return an anchor, which is, 42 pixels from the top of this view.  So it's something like ..
///For upstream views to know where the gauges area is at
var dialsSafeArea: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor {
    return something something 42 something
}

also good to know would be how to "modify" anchors, so,
///For upstream views to know where the gauges area is
var dialsSafeArea: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor {
    return topAnchor something something 3 something
    or say
    return pinkThing.topAnchor something something 3 something
}

I may be missing something obvious but I just have not been able to figure this out.
(A workaround is that you can pathetically make an invisible view, 42 down, and return that view's anchor!)
How to? Is it possible?

There are actually several ways to do this, depending on what exactly you're trying to do.

Let's say that the only way anything is ever going to be pinned to the top of a view is actually 42 pixels down from the top of the view. Then you can override that view's alignment rect insets:
override var alignmentRectInsets: UIEdgeInsets {
    .init(top: 42, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
}

The result is that we have effectively moved the position of this view's topAnchor, and anything that pins to this view's topAnchor will be measuring from a point 42 points down from the top of the physical view.
The nice thing about this approach is that it is automatic. No other views need to know about it; you just pin to the view's topAnchor and the right thing happens. This is very useful, for instance, when a view contains an inset drawing and what you want to do is pin to the edge of the drawing rather than the view itself.

Another approach is to set the top of your view's layout margins. Every view has margins, but they are very little used these days; this could be a good use of one. Simply say
myView.layoutMargins.top = 42

Now when you want to pin to that thing-that-is-42-points-down from the top of myView, pin to myView.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor.
(I suspect that this is in fact the approach you are really looking for.)

Still another approach, which is a bit more work, is for the view to vend a custom layout guide. (I say "custom" because the layoutMarginsGuide is already a built-in layout guide.) Call addLayoutGuide on the view to give it a layout guide, give the layout guide an identifier so you can find it again later, and then use constraints between the layout guide and the owning view to position the layout guide:
let guide = UILayoutGuide()
guide.identifier = "myCoolGuide"
myView.addLayoutGuide(guide)
guide.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.topAnchor, constant: 42).isActive = true
guide.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
// and so too for trailing and bottom

Then another view can be pinned to the top anchor of myView's layout guide rather than to the top anchor of myView itself. Writing code to get a reference to the layout guide is left as an exercise for the reader.
Note that this is not the same as the "pathetic" invisible view mentioned in your question, because a UILayoutGuide is not a view. It's just a kind of invisible dimensional "frame". Indeed, UILayoutGuide was invented (by Apple) exactly so that you could do this kind of thing without the added overhead of using invisible "spacer" views.

¡ INCREDIBLE !  further, alignmentRectInsets is an incredible tip

I wonder if you can vend a dimension anchor .. height or width .. I'll ask another question!

oh I see it actually then has all its own constraints, assuming you set enough.  wonderful

"Assuming" See the comment in my code, "and so too for trailing and bottom"? I left those two lines out but you are left to write them yourself, as an exercise. You must write them; you must set sufficient constraints on the layout guide, when you create it. After that, sure, it has a height and width and the whole bit. It is positioned just like a view — but it is not a view, it's just a calculational "frame".

lol yes I understood the superb answer!!!!  It turns out you can set as few constraints as you wish on the layout guide; if you just wanna vend say the top. (No errors: it looks like the solver is agnostic until it's asked something unsolvable.)  So great!  I put in a "single way" example

The margin is not the edge, so this is not attached to the left edge as you so loosely claim; rather, it is attached to the left margin which is a different thing. The alignment rect changes the top, left, bottom, and right anchors, but it does not affect the margins which are dictated by the layout margins guide.

I'm so sorry, there was a critical typo in my comment!  If you attach it to the left ANCHOR ... then ... I was very surprised to see that it seemingly attaches it to the ORIGINAL left edge, not the "new" left edge! I will have to investigate this and make a demo!

For anyone googling here, just another example from the superb ticked answer on this page; here a single guide only needed
Vendor ...
lazy var someTopAnchor: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor = {
    let g = UILayoutGuide()
    addLayoutGuide(g)
    g.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 42).isActive = true
    print("added/returned a layout anchor")
    return g.topAnchor
}()

upstream ...
lazy var red: UIView = {
    let v = UIView.Typical
    v.backgroundColor = .red
    view.addSubview(v)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
        v.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
        v.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 100),
        v.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mapView.someTopAnchor)
    ])
    return v
}()

real-world example use
///Use this to be above the "fine print" (Maps logo, 'legal' link)
///which UIKit adds to a map view.
lazy var finePrintSafaAreaBottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor = {
    let g = UILayoutGuide()
    addLayoutGuide(g)
    let bestGuessFinePrintView = {
        for v in subviews {
            if "MKAttributionLabel" .. etc etc
    }()
    let comfortable = bestGuessFinePrintView.minY - 8
    g.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor,
            constant: comfortable).isActive = true
    return g.topAnchor
}()

(*) Smartass tip ...
Animating the layout guides you vend can be a powerful way to encapsulate stuff.

I suppose you could do that; you could pin only the layout guide top, just as long as the layout guide top is the only anchor of the layout guide that you pin to. But I can't advise it; the layout guide's own layout is totally ambiguous, and that's bad.

Now that I see you trying to use it this way, I've added another approach to my answer; I've placed it second in the list. I suspect that this new second approach is the one you are really looking for.

another great technique!!!  I did previously use layoutMarginsGuide. Totally flexible anchors, as many as you need, are great to have.  (Regarding the "less than complete" layout guides issue: seems more logical to me (when you only want to vend one), note (my code Blok #1 here) it's only vending a NSLayoutYAxisAnchor, the guide is inaccessible (even to that class!) That layout guide "genuinely only is" a SSOT for the top anchor in question; ie if "someone else on the team" tried to use that guide to get a height, left etc, they would be conceptually totally misguided and it (should) crash. An

away you've saved the day again as always, brilliant!  its layout guides all over now.

(in re the "less than complete" layout guides; that being said, if the proverbial junior programmer happened along here, I'd just tell him "you saw nothing here, make it a complete rectangle" lol)

"it's only vending a NSLayoutYAxisAnchor" That is a great point! But I would still advise against incompleteness, even under the hood.
